# Why does extra __syncthreads() call cause unexpected behavior?

Tags: cuda

I'm using reduction code adapted from threadFenceReduction in the CUDA samples, which is also described in [this presentation (PDF)](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/samples/6_Advanced/reduction/doc/reduction.pdf).

While doing some debugging, I found that simply inserting an extra  __syncthreads() call, the reduction no longer gives the correct sum:

```
typedef int64_t SumType;

template <int blockSize>
static __device__ void
reduceBlock(
    SumType mySum,
    const unsigned int tid
    )
{
    // Each thread puts its local sum into shared memory 
    extern __shared__ SumType sdata[];
    sdata[tid] = mySum;
    __syncthreads();

    // Sum values at an offset of 128 and 64
    if( blockSize >= 256 ) { if (tid < 128) { sdata[tid] = mySum = mySum + (sdata[tid + 128]); } __syncthreads(); }
    if( blockSize >= 128 ) { if (tid <  64) { sdata[tid] = mySum = mySum + (sdata[tid +  64]); } __syncthreads(); }

    if( tid < 32 )
    {
        __syncthreads(); //  <=== Extra __syncthreads(), breaks reduction!

        // Synchronize within warp using volatile type
        volatile SumType *smem = sdata;
        if( blockSize >= 64 ) { smem[tid] = mySum = mySum + (smem[tid + 32]); }
        if( blockSize >= 32 ) { smem[tid] = mySum = mySum + (smem[tid + 16]); }
        if( blockSize >= 16 ) { smem[tid] = mySum = mySum + (smem[tid +  8]); }
        if( blockSize >=  8 ) { smem[tid] = mySum = mySum + (smem[tid +  4]); }
        if( blockSize >=  4 ) { smem[tid] = mySum = mySum + (smem[tid +  2]); }
        if( blockSize >=  2 ) { smem[tid] = mySum = mySum + (smem[tid +  1]); }
    }
}
```

Why would inserting an extra __syncthreads() cause this code to no longer work?

Please see my answer below for a self-contained code example.

Edit: moved __syncthreads() to be within if() statement in the example, to reflect the code that actually triggered the bug.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: The output to the caller of reduceBlock() is in shared memory, which is how it is done in the sample.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem had to do with __syncthreads() being called for only some of the threads in the block.  The end result was some very strange behavior. 
From the [CUDA C Programming Guide](http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#synchronization-functions), section B.6:

> __syncthreads() is allowed in conditional code but only if the conditional evaluates identically across the entire thread block,
>   otherwise the code execution is likely to hang or produce unintended
>   side effects.

I boiled it down to the following simple example.  The flag in shared memory s_onlyOneBlock gets set by one thread in each block; in block 0, it's true, while in other blocks it's false.  One would expect *all* of the threads in block 0 to get s_onlyOneBlock=true; however, because __syncthreads() only gets call for threads 0 to 31, the behavior is unexpected: only threads 0 to 31 get s_onlyOneBlock=true:

```
#include <stdio.h>

static __global__ void
kernel()
{
    __shared__ bool s_onlyOneBlock;
    const unsigned int tid = threadIdx.x;

    // Call __syncthreads() for only some threads (don't do this!)
    if( tid < 32 )
        __syncthreads();

    // Thread 0 sets s_onlyOneBlock
    if( tid == 0 )
        s_onlyOneBlock = ( blockIdx.x == 0 );

    __syncthreads();

    if( s_onlyOneBlock )
    {
        // Only block 0 should reach this point
        if( tid==0 || tid==31 || tid==32 || tid==128 )
            printf("s_onlyOneBlock is TRUE:  block=%d thread=%d\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x);
    }
    else
    {
        if( tid==0 || tid==31 || tid==32 || tid==128 )
            printf("s_onlyOneBlock is false: block=%d thread=%d\n", blockIdx.x, threadIdx.x);
    }
}

int main()
{
    kernel<<<2, 256>>>();
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
```

The result:

```
nvcc syncproblem.cu -o syncproblem
./syncproblem 
s_onlyOneBlock is false: block=0 thread=128  <--- should be true!
s_onlyOneBlock is false: block=1 thread=128
s_onlyOneBlock is false: block=0 thread=32   <--- should be true!
s_onlyOneBlock is false: block=1 thread=32
s_onlyOneBlock is TRUE:  block=0 thread=0
s_onlyOneBlock is TRUE:  block=0 thread=31
s_onlyOneBlock is false: block=1 thread=0
s_onlyOneBlock is false: block=1 thread=31
```